# Выделение запятыми: более важный

Tags: пунктуация

Есть отрывок из предложения:

> отвлекает внимание от других, более важных, вопросов.

Нужны ли здесь запятые вокруг "более важных"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если **считаете важным уточнение**,следует обособить,но нужно иметь в виду следующее:

1) Обособление уточняющих согласованных определений – явление достаточно редкое и во многом зависит от воли пишущего. Обычно определения с уточняющим значением рассматриваются как однородные, то есть запятая ставится не с двух сторон, а с одной – между определениями.

Быстрыми шагами прошёл я длинную «площадь» кустов, взобрался на холм и... увидел совершенно другие, незнакомые мне места (Тургенев).

Так что можно и так: отвлекает внимание от других, более важных  вопросов.